# Filter for failed BigQuery jobs in the webinterface

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a lot of jobs that have run (over 1000) and some of them failed. I can grep for them on the command line with
`bq ls -j --max_results=10000 | grep FAILURE` and then check each job id with `bq show --format=prettyjson -j JOB_ID`.

I can filter for jobs in the webinterface, but the filter does not allow me to filter for failed jobs only. At least I cannot see it:

[image: BigQuery Webinterface filter dropdown]

Is it possible to filter for failed jobs in the webinterface?

Comment: Could the people who downvoted this question maybe comment on why they did so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m with GCP Support. At the moment, it is not possible to filter like that.

As I think this is a good request, I have filled a Feature Request for this in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/78321982), where you can follow the updates of this FR.